# How are Wordpress plugins differentiated by Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created a wordpress plugin and uploaded it to my test site, but under `Plugins` wordpress informs me that there is update available to my plugin and it takes me to a completely separate plugin on wordpress.org

Why is wordpress confusing them?
How are plugins differentiated from each other as unique? Should I have a unique code or something?

What is it in my plugin which is the same as the plugin Wordpress is confusing it with?

Answer (score 1):

Guessing you should check the metadata at the top of your plugin (in comments):

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Name Of The Plugin
Plugin URI: http://URI_Of_Page_Describing_Plugin_and_Updates
Description: A brief description of the Plugin.
Version: The Plugin's Version Number, e.g.: 1.0
Author: Name Of The Plugin Author
Author URI: http://URI_Of_The_Plugin_Author
License: A "Slug" license name e.g. GPL2
*/
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

WordPress calls out to `http://api.wordpress.org/plugins/update-check/1.0/` intermittently to determine if there is a new version of the plugin available.  The call out is checking the WordPress plugin directory.

Your Plugin Name must be unique, otherwise you run the risk of colliding on this check with another plugin (as you have).  The plugin name is set in the plugin meta data in the comment section at the top of the main plugin file.

Another way to avoid this issue is to set your plugin version number to a ridiculously high number as the check does a version number compare to determine if a newer version is available.  This work around would only be if you never intend to release your plugin on the WordPress plugin directory or in to the wild.

As an interesting side note, the check also sends along your blog URL and a list of all installed plugins, so WordPress in Googlesk fashion most likely is collecting usage data.